# i want to add restriction on the modification variable

Tags: solidity, security

i want to share my code and see if someone help me to understand if it's a good practice ?

i would like to restrited the modification of the number.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract test {

    mapping (address => uint) num;

    modifier entier(uint _uint){
        //test si le num est un entier
        require(_uint > 0,'ca ne peut pas etre egal a 0');
        _;
    }

    uint public Setblocknumber;

    modifier blockSet() {
        require(uint(block.number) != Setblocknumber,'the user has already modified the num on this block');
        _;
    }

    function getSetBlocknumber() view public returns(uint){
        return Setblocknumber;
    }

    function getNum() view public returns(uint){
        return num[msg.sender];
    }

    function setNum(uint _uint) public entier(_uint) blockSet(){
        num[msg.sender] += _uint;
        Setblocknumber = uint(block.number);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but consider using [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/) instead of revert reason strings. Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant.

Comment: thanks @PaulRazvanBerg, do you have any example please ?

Comment: there are several examples in the URL I linked in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

as like you included `blockSet()`, include `OnlyOWner()` on `setNum()` function.

```
modifier OnlyOwner{
   require(msg.sender==0xOwnerAddress,'only owner can modify number');
}
```

Comment: if i do that, only one user can set a num for his address right ?

Comment: @KarlBlock it seems to me that you're missing some fundamental bits of knowledge about how Ethereum smart contracts work. I suggest you go through a beginner development tutorial [such as this one](https://hardhat.org/tutorial).

Comment: ok, thanks i will follow this tuto. i will be back :)